# Failed to retrieve logs from Log Cache

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

[Unable to push app to IBM cloud due error 404 that says Staging app and tracing logs...
Failed to retrieve logs from Log Cache: unexpected status code 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S21p6.png)

Comment: Hi Denis, it looks like your question doesn't have enough info to help you. A quick guess, 404 is a http status code that usually means the server is working, but the url path is incorrect. Try to find the API it is trying to connect to, then you can figure out why that path is not found.

Comment: Hi there, it seems like your question does not provide enough information for us to help you.